# How to disable canActivate for an internal redirect?

Tags: angular

This is my app-routing-module:

```
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [XCheck]
  }
  {
    path: 'page',
    component: PageComponent
  }
```

And I have a redirect from page to home in the page.html like this:

```
<a routerLink="/home">
```

I want to disable canActivate for the internal redirects. Is there any other way of doing this other than this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class XCheck implements CanActivate {

  constructor() {
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {


     .. Here I can somehow check if the previous URL is the URL of page...


    return .... (my current http.get)
  }
}
```

Comment: state has what was before, next what will be..... so what more do you need?

Comment: which attribute? I did not see the previous route/url

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Your canActivate function will run anyway, if performance is your concern.

Comment: i dont want to run an http.get for example..

Comment: do not just guess without knowing it! state.url gives the target url.